# To what polynomials are the Legendre Polynomials orthogonal beside themselves?

Tags: calculus, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

In my practice exam there was the question whether this is true:

$\int_{-1}^{1}P_5(x)x^3dx$=0

$P_5$ Is the 5th legendre polynomial.

The answer is yes and they state that this follows from the orthogonality of the legendre polynomials. I know that the legendre polynomials are orthogonal to each other but why should they be orthogonal to $x^3$?

Comment: You can express $x^3=a P_3+ b P_2 + c P_1 +d P_0$, once you have done that, by orthogonality, $\langle P_5,x^3 \rangle=0$.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense. So, with the same argument, is $P_n$ orthogonal to any polynomial of degree less than $n$?

Comment: Answer to your last comment: yes, and this is valid for any family of classical orthogonal polynomials.

Comment: @JeanMarie This is valid for any family of orthogonal polynomials. The classical polynomials are associated with differential equations of the second degree.

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc You are right, the adjective "classical" was superfluous.